# Nested populate array of ObjectId

Tags: node.js, arrays, populate, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to `populate` `array of ObjectId` in `mongoose`. And inside that array, will need `populate` again.

Let's say I've `User` data schema as below:-

- `models/User.js`

  ```
  /** Dependencies */
  // Mongoose
  const mongoose = require('mongoose')

  /** Data Schema */
  // User Data Schema
  const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      // User's Name
      name: {
          // User's Firstname
          firstName: { type: String, required: true, min: 4 },
          // User's Lastname
          lastName: { type: String, required: true, min: 4 }
      },
      // User's Address Array[ID]
      address: [{
          // AddressID
          addressID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Address" },
      }]
  })

  /** Data Schema Exports */
  module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
  ```
- and `Address` schema, `models/Address.js`

  ```
  /** Dependencies */
  // Mongoose
  const mongoose = require('mongoose')

  /** Data Schema */
  // Address Data Schema
  const AddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      // Address 1
      addressOne: { type: String, required: true },
      // Address 2
      addressTwo: { type: String },
      // Postcode
      postcode: { type: String, required: true },
      // City
      city: { type: String, required: true },
      // StateID
      state: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "State" },
      // CountryID
      country: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Country" }
  })

  // State Data Schema
  const StateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      // Gender's Name
      name: { type: String, required: true }
  })

  // Country Data Schema
  const CountrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      // Race's Name
      name: { type: String, required: true }
  })

  /** Data Schema Export */
  const Address = mongoose.model('Address', AddressSchema)
  const State = mongoose.model('State', StateSchema)
  const Country = mongoose.model('Country', CountrySchema)
  module.exports = {
      Address,
      State,
      Country
  }
  ```

I know how to `populate` `state` & `country` from `Address`, like show below:-

```
Address.find()
.populate('state')
.populate('country')
.then(async address => {
    // do stuff
})
.catch(err => res.json({ err }))
```

But how can I `populate` array of `ObjectId`. I did the code like shown below:-

```
User.findById({ _id: userId }) // let's say I've the userId
.populate('address')
.then(async user => {
    console.log(await user)
})
.catch(err => res.json({ err }))
```

Unfortunately, It `returns` me something like this:-

```
{
    "_id": "5fabababababababababab1"
    "name": {
        "firstName": "Lalapolalaa",
        "lastName": "Newb"
    },
    "address": [
        {
            "_id": "5fcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc1",
            "addressID": "5fefefefefefefefefef1" // should've populate (but not working)
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0   
}
```

What I'm trying to get is like shown below:-

```
{
    "_id": "5fabababababababababab1"
    "name": {
        "firstName": "Lalapolalaa",
        "lastName": "Newb"
    },
    "address": [
        {
            "_id": "5fcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc1",
            "addressID": { // populate happens here
                "_id": "5fefefefefefefefefef1",
                "addressOne": "Lot 1, Street 12",
                "addressTwo": "SS 21",
                "postcode" : "47500",
                "city": "Subang Jaya",
                "state": { // populate happens here
                    "_id": "5fghghghghghghghghg1",
                    "name": "Selangor",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "country": { // populate happens here
                    "_id": "5ijijijijijijijijij1",
                    "name": "Malaysia",
                    "__v": 0
                }
                "__v": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0   
}
```

How can I get that (shown above) with my current code below:-

```
User.findById({ _id: userId }) // let's say I've the userId
.populate('address') // assuming this populate of address works
.then(async user => {
    // how to populate state & country of Address?
    // code below only return address[0] information (assumption)
    const address = await Address.findById({ _id: user.address[0].addressID._id })
    .populate('state')
    .populate('country')
    .then(address => address)
})
.catch(err => res.json({ err }))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to find the solution myself with below corrections:-

- in `models/User.js`:-

```js
/** Dependencies */
// Mongoose
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

/** Data Schema */
// User Data Schema
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // User's Name
    name: {
        // User's Firstname
        firstName: { type: String, required: true, min: 4 },
        // User's Lastname
        lastName: { type: String, required: true, min: 4 }
    },
    // User's Address Array[ID]
    address: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Address" }] // 1st Correction
})

/** Data Schema Exports */
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Then next I can straight code like shown below (**SOLUTION**):-

```js
User.findById({ _id: userId }) // let's say I've the userId
.populate('address') // assuming this populate of address works
.then(async user => {
    // create an array to hold JUST the IDs of Address available
    let addressesID = []
    // transfer all Address's ID
    for(let i = 0; i < (user.address).length; i++) {
        // push available address's ID one by one
        addressesID.push(user.address[i]._id)
    }
    // get all address info available in Address (from DB) 
    const addresses = await Address.find(
        { _id: { $in: addressesID } }
    )
    .populate('state')
    .populate('country')
    .then(address => address)
})
.then(all => console.log(all))
.catch(err => res.json({ err }))
```

it will then `console.log()`

```js
{
    _id: '5fabababababababababab1',
    name: {
        firstName: 'Lalapolalaa',
        lastName: 'Newb'
    },
    address: { // populate happens here
        _id: '5fefefefefefefefefef1',
        addressOne: 'Lot 1, Street 12',
        addressTwo: 'SS 21',
        postcode" : '47500',
        city: 'Subang Jaya',
        state: { // populate happens here
            _id: '5fghghghghghghghghg1',
            name: 'Selangor',
            __v: 0
        },
        country: { // populate happens here
            _id: '5ijijijijijijijijij1',
            name: 'Malaysia',
            __v: 0
        },
        __v: 0
    },
    __v: 0
}
```